# Java - How to add a JOptionPane for Yes and No options

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane

So, I've read the Java API, but still can't seem to make heads or tails about how to do this. And believe me I have tried. I want an ActionListener to cause a message box with the text 'Do you really want to exit?', with options yes and no which exits the program or not depending on the selected button.

Here's what I have for the ActionListener before I started to break it with the message box:

```
exitItem.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        window.dispose();
                    }
                }
                );
```

How can I suitably change it to meet my requirements?

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). *QED*.

Comment: Did you try JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this inside your `ActionListener`:

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                  "Do you wanna close the window?", 
                                  "Choose", 
                                  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    window.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
"The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
+ "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
+ "Do you understand?",
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

[image]

Comment: IIRC, you will need a `.show()` or something as well for the dialogue to display.

Comment: @nidhin : Why cann't you close this with the RED X Button on the top right side ? Good example though +1 for that, you just forgot how to show it part.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you", "Message", 
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

It will return 0 for Yes and 1 for No

Answer (score 3):

not clear what do you really want to do, maybe

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();

    public ClosingFrame() {
        File.add(Exit);
        MenuBar.add(File);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                        "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame1.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame1.setLocation(500, 100);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Whatever", "Whatever",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            int confirm1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame1,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClosingFrame cf = new ClosingFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```