# Get the application closing event

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, formclosing, jsr296

How to get to the application closing event?

I want to get application to save all unsaved operations or show the user a message "Are you sure about closing without saving all data?" something like this.

If this will be helpful - the application is a `SingleFrameAplication` using Swing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-). It works for Swing, AWT and even console applications.

**Example:**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: be cautious using roseindia links. please read http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html
I would reccomend http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread) as a link instead

Comment: @Sean, thanks for the warning! I have edited the answer with a more legitimate link.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to your `JFrame / JDialog`, about closing event is there  method public `void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {` code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228595/714968)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sun.misc.Signal` or `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook`

[More info](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/)