# Show prompt before closing JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am using `windowClosing` to confirm before closing a particular JFrame.

Before closing I get a confirm dialog but the problem is it closes even if I click the NO button. Any help please?

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
  { 
    String ObjButtons[] = {"Yes","No"};
    int PromptResult = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
        "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Online Examination System", 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, 
        ObjButtons,ObjButtons[1]);
    if(PromptResult==0)
    {
      System.exit(0);          
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your JFrame's default close operation set to? Has it been set to: `jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`?

Comment: `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?","Online Examination System",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,ObjButtons,ObjButtons[1]);`: Don't pass `null` for the first argument. Pass the parent frame of the dialog, otherwise your optionpane dialog may go behind your frame.

Comment: Please mark an answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What is your JFrame's default close operation set to? You need to make sure that it been set to: `jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: @user2125727 [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9228595/714968)

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    { 
        String ObjButtons[] = {"Yes","No"};
        int PromptResult = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?","Online Examination System",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,ObjButtons,ObjButtons[1]);
        if(PromptResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you edit that code sample so that it's formatted correctly. It's unreadable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default close option of your JFrame to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` if it is set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. In that case it will resolve your query something like:-

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 2):

put this on on frame intialization

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```