# Java jFrame close button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi i have a jFrame and I wish to ask the user whether he is sure to close the jframe when the close button is clicked:

```
    this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
    Main ma = new Main();

    Object[] options = {"Yes", "NO"};

    int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(ma, "Are you sure you want to close the system?", "Warning",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[0]);

           if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
               System.exit(0);
           }

    else
    {
    }

    }
    });
```

How shall i undo the close operation when he selects the 'NO' button from the jpanel popup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show prompt before closing JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449022/show-prompt-before-closing-jframe)

Comment: There is no need to have an else there. Only exits if yes-option selected else the application keeps running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to set the JFrame's default close action to do nothing on close:

```
myJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then pressing the close button will not close the JFrame, and you will have to dispose of it in code.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default close operation to `JFrame.DO_NOTHING`, then use a `WindowListener` and listen for the `windowClosing` event. To close the frame now all you need to do is call `dispose()` on the frame. So:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)  
{  
    JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getWindow();  
    if (canClose(frame)) // you define canClose  
    {  
        frame.dispose();  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // other stuff  
    }  
}
```