# MessageBox when closing

Tags: java, messagebox

I looking for create mechanism for messaging when exiting and changes has been made.
  I want it to display a messagebox asking the user :
  ( Are you sure you don't want to save the changes - yes / no)

Upon closing the form by clicking on the button named 'Exit' or when use close button, ''X".  Don't know the syntax for it, can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you using a JFrame?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449022/show-prompt-before-closing-jframe

Comment: Just check for `yes` and other(cancel/close/exit) will fall in else part.

Comment: Are you using a JFrame? –  codeNinja  -> yes, i use

Answer (score 1):

Here's some basic code on how to do it:

```
public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {
    public ClosingFrame() {
        super("Shutdown hook");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); /* important */

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.
                        showConfirmDialog(ClosingFrame.this, "Do you want to save?");
                if (showConfirmDialog == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("saved");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (showConfirmDialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("not saved");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("aborted");
                    // do nothing
                }
            }

        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ClosingFrame());
    }

}
```

Comment: @EmlX You're welcome. If it was what you were looking for, please be so kind and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Yes, it's useful but still is not what exactly i look for. I use your answer, but this is only half from this what i need.