# Java : Frame responds on pop-up action. how?

Tags: java, swing, frame, jbutton

in my frame A JTable and SAVE button is there.
i enter data into JTable and save it to the DATABASE.
in my current programe:

When i clicked "SAVE" button it checks the data and pushes it to database..

My concern is:

When "SAVE" button will be clicked, a frame with two button (OK & CANCEL) asking (Are you sure to save the record?) will trigger. Then, If OK button is clicked,the data in JTable will be pushed to the DATBASE.

Comment: Please, add more details: language, environment. Also, please show what did you already try.

Comment: You need to post the code of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`When "SAVE" button will be clicked, a frame with two button (OK & CANCEL) asking (Are you sure to save the record?) will trigger. Then, If OK button is clicked,the data in JTable will be pushed to the DATBASE.`

use [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features), then there you can test for [required returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228595/714968)