# Exiting loop when user clicks "cancel" or finishes number of allowed attempts

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, joptionpane

I want to code a loop that ends when the user has used up their three tries, clicks cancel or closes the window with the red x. The red x and using up the three tries portion work fine. But the cancel button is being useless and acting the same as the OK button.

I have written an if statement but it is ineffective. The window that prompts the user for a password continues to pop up until all allowed attempts are used up even when the user presses cancel. This is what I have so far:

```
    String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};

    int tries = 0;

    String passString = "";

    int option = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;

    while (!isValidPassword(passString) && tries < 3) {

            option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The title",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[1]);


            if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1-)You should increase the tries in while loop.

```
String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};

int tries = 0;

String passString = "";

int option = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;

while (!isValidPassword(passString) && tries < 3) {

    option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The title",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[1]);

    tries++;

    if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Where did this i come from? I don't have an i in my while loop.

Comment: I did increase the tries I just forgot to include it in the post because I didn't copy and paste correctly. My issue is mostly with the if (option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) statement. It does not work, when the user clicks cancel the loop still continues and the dialog boxes continue to pop up.

Comment: @Jason_Silva  you can check this topic   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367242/ask-user-if-wants-to-quit-via-joptionpane

Answer (score 0):

Use the JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION instead of JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION and this should fix the issue. After the change your code would be like below

```
String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};

int tries = 0;

String passString = "";

int option = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;

while (!isValidPassword(passString) && tries < 3) {

        option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The title",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[1]);


        if (option == JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION || option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            break;
        }
```