# Perform an action as soon as user closes (Xs out) JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Basically it's a client program with a GUI so I want to close the sockets when the user closes the client program. Is there is Listener or something that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Aside: what exactly do you hope to accomplish by changing the close operation for a window *after* it's closed? Or even just before it's closing? Usually it's enough to call `setDefaultCloseOperation()` at the start of your program.

Comment: Well, I did that only because syb0rg below suggested it.

Comment: If all you want to do is clean up when the application is closed, try taking a look at [Shitdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sorry I'm a noob. I'll need an example to understand.

Comment: @AnAlien For example you could read the javadocs. Or google for "java shutdown hook example".

Comment: @AnAlien Start by having a look at the link provided (sorry about the spelling :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Note that this will *only* be called when the default close operation has been set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` *before* the frame is closed via the (x) button. The default is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` which technically does not close the window, therefore the listener would not be notified.

Comment: I'm not sure if windowClosed will ever get called under these circumstances, windowClosing is a safer bet - needs to be tested

Comment: @MadProgrammer Should work because the only difference should be when the listener is notified (before or after the frame is gone), but just to be safe I changed it ;)

Comment: From experince, I tend to avoid windowClosed, because I think the JVM is closed before it is called, when using EXIT_ON_CLOSE, I could've wrong, been a while since I did things ths way ;)

Comment: Even thought it didn't work for me, everyone else said basically the same thing except you were first so I select you as the right answer. Thanks for trying. I'm posting a new question regarding this code and how to make it actually work.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) for the closing event:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

For more help, look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) on `WindowListener`'s.

Comment: You have to set the *default close operation* to *do nothing* on close.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, what is the parameter for nothing?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not in all cases.  From the code I took this from, I set the close operation to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` right before I add this window listener, and it works perfectly. You could also set the close operation within the `WindowClosing` event (I edited this into the answer).

Comment: So I have a class which extends JFrame so I did: `this.addWindow......`
And inside the windowClosed method, to test it out I have a println statement. But it doesn't get printed out when I close the JFrame.

Comment: @AnAlien No, look at my edited answer to try and get a better understanding.

Comment: @AnAlien Change `this.setDefaultCloseOperation` to `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation`.

Comment: But frame isn't a variable. I'm doing this from within the constructor which is why I'm using this

Comment: @AnAlien You have to make a new `JFrame` object somewhere. Whatever you named that object, that is what you have to set the close operation for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29450/discussion-between-an-alien-and-syb0rg)

Comment: [without jokes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9228595/714968), resutl could be == not to required something to change, lets this job ro WindowListener

Comment: @mKorbel I'm sorry, I don't understand that.

Comment: see my code example linked in my comment, WindowListener to override events (about JFrame, JFrame has three buttons) from buttons, by using this code you can to try any possible variations, but logics could be JFrame.setVisible(false), then whatever code, if code ended then to call System.exit

Comment: I'm not sure if changing the default close operation AFTER the window has begun closing is going to do anything...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found some example online somewhere that had it like that, and I followed it and it seemed to work.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @syb0rg As I said, I wasn't sure, it just seems very...weird to try and change the state of the operation mid stream, that's all

Answer (score 1):

To refer to `this` from an enclosing scope, use this:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        this.addWindowListener(
            // omitting AIC boilerplate

            // Use the name of the enclosing class
            MyFrame.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or store it in a variable with a different name:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        final JFrame thisFrame = this;
        this.addWindowListener(
            // omitting AIC boilerplate

            // Use the name of the enclosing class
            thisFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my main code and nothing happens when I close JFrame.

Comment: @AnAlien You edited your question to be a completely different one than the one I answered. This is "moving the goalposts", it's a behaviour that's frowned upon, don't do this. Work on the new problem yourself, and post a new question when stuck. (The new question should explain what you're trying to accomplish for instance.)

Comment: Well, the problem still is the same. It's just that I'm trying out everyone's different answers and none seem to be working. I can't get anything to happen when user closes JFrame.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm still trying to accomplish the same thing which is to perform an action once user closes/Xs JFrame.

Comment: @AnAlien No, that's just the task you're trying to ultimately accomplish. But that's not the problem your original question described, and your edit changed it *substantially*. SO should be about resolving isolated problems, not to guide you through your work until it's complete.

Comment: I understand now, sorry. I'll just rollback and post a new question.